# How do I use a boost::program_options notifier with multiple options?

Tags: c++, file-io, boost-program-options

I'm writing a physics simulation that reads in a whole bunch of system parameters with the [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options.html) library and I'd like to "automatically" set some parameters that arise as combinations of the user-input values. For example, if I have

```
[parameters]
    c0 = 299792458
    dt = 0.004
```

as the speed of light and timestep in my input file, I'd like to set a value `cdt = c0*dt` in the same structure I'm using to store `c0` and `dt` after both options get read. Notifiers, as I understand, are a way to process *an* input option with a function, but I haven't seen a way to do the same thing with *multiple* options -- what's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any direct option how to achieve this using boost program_options. Notifiers are being called after only one option is parsed. However you can combine several workarounds to achieve acceptable solution - store values in separate structure, let program_options to fill all computed values (directly or using setter function) after parsing is complete.

My simplified suggestion:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::program_options;

struct SimulationConfig {
  int c0;
  float dt;
  float cdt;

  void setCdt() {
    cdt = c0*dt;
  }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  SimulationConfig config;
  try
  {
    options_description desc{"Options"};
    desc.add_options()
      ("help,h", "Help screen")
      ("c0", value<int>(&config.c0), "Speed of light")
      ("dt", value<float>(&config.dt), "Time interval");

    variables_map vm;
    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    notify(vm);


    if (vm.count("help"))
      std::cout << desc << '\n';
    else if (vm.count("c0") && vm.count("dt")) {
      //config.cdt = vm["c0"].as<int>() * vm["dt"].as<float>();
      config.setCdt();
      std::cout << "Cdt is set to: " << config.cdt << std::endl;
    }

  }
  catch (const error &ex)
  {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a config struct like pe3k recommends you are nearly there. Just add a notifier which calls the according setter:

```
options_description desc{"Options"};
desc.add_options()
  ("help,h", "Help screen")
  ("c0",
   value<int>(&config.c0),
   "Speed of light")
  ("dt",
   value<float>(&config.dt)->notifier([&config](auto){ config.setCdt(); }),
   "Time interval");
```